# How to find multiple indices in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with repeated values

```
array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5])
```

I would like to find indices for a closest value, e.g 3.3
I think I need to use `numpy.argmin` but I do not know how to do that.
 Could someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "A numpy array with identical values"? Could you also elaborate on your what your question/problem is? Do you mean you want to find the indices of all of the values in a list that are "close" to a given number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the **first** value that is closest to your input, you could look at the index where the absolute difference is lowest. Something like so:

```py
closest_idx = np.abs(array - 3.3).argmin()
```

To then find the *indices* of **all values** that have the same (closest) value:

```py
closest_val = array[min_idx]
all_closest_idx = np.argwhere(array == closest_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>> import numpy as np
>> value_search = 3.3
>> array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5])
```

You should use `np.argsort`: the closet one is 2nd index (number 3) then 7th  (number 3 as well) then ...

```
>> np.argsort(abs(array - value_search))
array([2, 7, 3, 8, 1, 6, 4, 9, 0, 5]
```